# How can I combine www. and https redirects into one redirect?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site that is giving me SSL Certificate warnings, I believe because my website is trying to redirect to www prior to loading https. Here are my htaccess settings, is there any way for me to handle both redirects at one time instead of having to redirect twice?

```
### Force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

### Force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `[OR]` flag to redirect if the request is missing the www *or* if it's not HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, this isn't going to prevent people getting SSL certificate warnings. If your cert is registered for "www.domain.com" and someone goes to `https://domain.com/` first, they'll get a warning regardless of the order of redirecting.